# Missing table name in IntegrityError (Django ORM)

Tags: python, django, postgresql, django-orm

I am missing the table name in IntegrityError of Django:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
...
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File ".../django/db/utils.py", line 94, in __exit__
    six.reraise(dj_exc_type, dj_exc_value, traceback)
  File ".../django/db/backends/utils.py", line 64, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
IntegrityError: null value in column "manager_slug" violates not-null constraint
DETAIL:  Failing row contains (17485, null, 2017-10-10 09:32:19, , 306).
```

Is there a way to see which table the INSERT/UPDATE is accessing?

We use PostgreSQL 9.6.

**This is a generic question**: How to get a better error message?

This is not a  question about this particular column. I found the relevant table and column very soon. But I want to improve the error message which is from our CI system. The next time I want to see the table name immediately.

I know that I could reveal the missing information easily with a debugger if I see this error during software development. But in my case this happens in production, and I have only the stacktrace like above.

Comment: share your model

Comment: @Shaonshaonty there is no need to share my model. This is a generic question: How to get a better error message? This is not a  question about this particular column.

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something, but would the stack trace not show which Django model you were manipulating? e.g., if a model's `save()` method was what triggered the exception, then that would appear in your stack trace.

Comment: In my case I removed migration files and then again done makemigrations, and all works for me.

Comment: @TejasTank you did not read/understand this: **This is a generic question**: How to get a better error message? 

This is not a  question about this particular column.

Comment: @guettli in respecte to django, you had to read their documanation, I given tips to quick resolve, Yes. in generic, their always refere offical documentation. According offical django of your follow, pretty much eacy things for you. I just give tips to quick fix, as it worked for me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The exception message in this traceback is the original message from the database driver. It is useful to know this and the traceback if anything is googled, reported etc.

The exception class is the same django.db.utils.**IntegrityError** for all backends, but the message or rather arguments depend on the backend:

- **postgres**: `null value in column "manager_slug" violates not-null constraint\n` `DETAILS...\n`
- **mysql** . . : `(1048, "Column 'manager_slug' cannot be null")`
- **sqlite3** . : `NOT NULL constraint failed: appname_modelname.manager_slug`

The table name is visible only with `sqlite3` backend. Some backends use only a string argument of exception, but `mysql` uses two arguments: a numeric error code and a message. (I like to accept that it is a general question, not only PostgreSQL.) Authors of some backends expect that the author of the app will know the table name directly or from SQL, but it is not true with general ORM packages. There is no preferable and generally acceptable way, how to extend the message even if it can be done technically perfect.

Development and debugging are easy:

- Much additional information is available in DEBUG mode in development ("SQL" in the last frame or a class name of an object on a line like "myobj.save()")
- `python manage.py test --debug-sql`: "Prints logged SQL queries on failure."
- The same error in development/tests with sqlite3 is easier readable.

...but you are probably asking for a run-time error in production.

I guess about your possible intention in a so general question, what direction could be interesting for you.

**A)** The most important information from the **traceback** is usually a few lines **above** the many lines with **".../django/db/..."**. It is perfectly easy for a guru. It can be used very probably if the code is not so dynamic and general like a Django admin site, where no code near `myobj.save()` call (neither in parent frames) contains an explicit model name. Example:

```
# skip some initial universal code in ".../django/..."
...
# our apps start to be interesting... (maybe other installed app)
...
# START HERE: Open this line in the editor. If the function is universal, jump to the previous.
File ".../me/app/...py", line 47, in my...
  my_obj.save()
# skip many stack frames .../django/db/... below
File ".../django/db/models/base.py", line 734, in save
  # self.save_base(...    # this line 733 is not visible
      force_update=force_update, update_fields=update_fields)
...
# interesting only sql and params, but not visible in production
File ".../django/db/backends/utils.py", line 64, in execute
  return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
IntegrityError (or DataError similarly)...
```

**B)** Catch the information by a common ancestor of your models

```
class ...(models.Model):
    def save(self, *args, **wkargs):
        try:
            super(..., self).save(*args, **wkargs)
        except django.db.utils.IntegrityError as exc:
            new_message = 'table {}'.format(self._meta.db_table)
            exc.extra_info = new_message
            # this is less compatible, but it doesn't require additional reading support
            # exc.args = exc.args + (new_message,)
            reraise
```

This could complicate debugging with multiple inheritance.

**C)** An **implementation in Django db** would be better, but I can not imagine that it will be accepted and not reverted after some issue.

Comment: @hynecker: Yes, your are right. I updated the question: I know that I could reveal the missing information easily with a debugger if I see this error during software development. But in my case this happens in production, and I have only the stacktrace like above.

Comment: @hynecker: thank you for calling me "guru". Up to now I think "I know that I know nothing" :-)

Comment: @guettli: Added an example traceback to A).

Comment: Thank you for calling me "guru". I still think I know much less then a lot of experts. Nevertheless I wrote down my personal programming guidelines. Feedback welcome: https://github.com/guettli/programming-guidelines

Comment: I remove it from the answer. I think still your questions surprise finally, even if they looked simple. A motivation of an altruist can surprise more than of a competitive person.

Comment: "altruist" ... I am unsure. I just want the error message to better the next time. I updated the question: This is not a  question about this particular column. I found the relevant table and column very soon. But I want to improve the error message which is from our CI system. The next time I want to see the table name immediately.

Answer (score 2):

if you can create sql function you can try:

create function to get last sequence value get_sequence_last_value ([original post](http://grokbase.com/t/postgresql/pgsql-general/037rtrbysw/list-last-value-of-all-sequences))

```
CREATE FUNCTION public.get_sequence_last_value(name) RETURNS int4 AS '
DECLARE
ls_sequence ALIAS FOR $1;
lr_record RECORD;
li_return INT4;
BEGIN
FOR lr_record IN EXECUTE ''SELECT last_value FROM '' || ls_sequence LOOP
li_return := lr_record.last_value;
END LOOP;
RETURN li_return;
END;' LANGUAGE 'plpgsql' VOLATILE;
```

after it get table with sequence more then in error stack, and has column `manager_slug`

```
SELECT table_name, column_name 
FROM information_schema.columns 
WHERE table_name in (
    SELECT table_name

    FROM (
        SELECT table_name,
               get_sequence_last_value(
                    substr(column_default, 10, strpos(column_default, '::regclass') - 11)
                    ) as lv
        FROM information_schema.columns 
        WHERE column_default LIKE 'nextval%'
        ) as t_seq_lv

    WHERE lv > 17485
    )
   AND column_name = 'manager_slug';
```

i understand that the solution not full, but any way i hope it can help you

Comment: +1 It is an excellent "forensic" method if you can freeze a database copy immediately after an attack etc., but too late after CI tests. If I understand, many CI services recycle the test environment including the db immediately.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest to use Sentry (https://sentry.io/welcome/). In Sentry Issues you can observe all local variables for all parts of a stack trace.[image: screenshot of a sentry issue]

Comment: Sentry looks good. Thank you for the hint. Nevertheless it would be nice to have this important information (table name) in the default text representation. Sentry looks very good for production environments. I am unsure if it is usable for CI systems, too.

Comment: You can set several projects: for dev, staging and production. But I'm not sure whether Sentry suits for Docker Containers with branches for each Ticket.

Comment: "Docker Containers with branches for each Ticket." I don't know how you came to this conclusion. Up to now I don't use containers.

Comment: I didn't mean, that you necessary use Docker. I just pointed out a CI scenario where Sentry may be not the best solution. Why do you think, that Sentry may not suit for CI systems?

Comment: thank you for your interest. First I want to try sentry for prod systems. Then I will evaluate if it is feasible to use it for CI systems.

Comment: +1: It is a good idea, but it can be a security problem that most local variables are dumped to foreign servers at any exception. It requires to set [sensitive data filtering](https://docs.sentry.io/learn/sensitive-data/) and to check it also with regard to [GDPR](http://eur-lex.europa.eu/legal-content/EN/TXT/?qid=1501688126470&uri=CELEX:32016R0679) (European data protection law).

Comment: @hynekcer It's your server. Sentry is not a service, but the application on your server. The admin can control it entirely.

Answer (score 2):

The best solution that I have found to your problem is overwriting `DataBaseErrorWrapper` method, to do that go to `\django\db\utils.py` and in the line 86 replace `dj_exc_value = dj_exc_type(*exc_value.args)` for:

```
if exec_value.diag:
    a, b = exc_value.args + ("In the table '%s'" % exc_value.diag.table_name,)
    dj_exc_value = dj_exc_type(a + b)
else:
    dj_exc_value = dj_exc_type(*exc_value.args)
```

and if the IntegrityError appears, the message should work

```
django.db.utils.IntegrityError: null value in column "signature" violates not-null constraint
DETAIL:  Failing row contains (89, null).
In the table 'teachers_signature'
```

I am not sure but this should work with these exceptions:

```
DataError
OperationalError
IntegrityError
InternalError
ProgrammingError
NotSupportedError
```

It works for me, tell me if works to you. Remember edit the file with the Django folder that you are working

Comment: I think that it is not currently a solution for MySQL. It should be noted or it can be fixed. (see my compare of exception args for some backends)

Comment: The very useful attribute `diag` ([Diagnostics()](http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/extensions.html#psycopg2.extensions.Diagnostics) class) is supported only by the driver psycopg2 >= 2.5. It is required by Django 1.11, but Django 1.10 supports also 2.4.5. It should be definitely fixed to never raise AttributeError "diag" accidentally instead of database errors.

Comment: Any error in `DatabaseErrorWrapper.__exit__` is very serious because this method is important for closing unusable connections after some database errors. This could also break next requests if they are not closed correctly.

Comment: @hynekcer you are right. Is there some solution for that

Comment: +1: For an idea with the method `DatabaseErrorWrapper.__exit__` or context manager `wrap_database_errors`. This could be the best solution if it will be improved to quality near to Django pull request. (They recommend to start discussion at Django-developers because it is better if more people have objections e.g. compatibility with debug toolbars and other tools that work with exception args, sooner than after issues.) I edited my answer, to be clear that at the end of messages of other backends is no white space.

Answer (score 0):

You miss set value at column "manager_slug". You cant set NULL value at this column. You should set value or remove not-null condition.

```
IntegrityError: null value in column "manager_slug" violates not-null constraint
```

Comment: Please look at the question again. I underlined that this is a general question.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way to see which table the INSERT/UPDATE is accessing?

If you're running `migrate`, you could just visit up the stdout and check which migration is being executed. Then you can open the migration file and have a better overview of the issue.

If you don't i guess you want to take a look at [PEP249](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0249/#optional-error-handling-extensions) for optional error handling. as django database wrappper is based on PEP249 specification.

References on django code within [DatabaseErrorWrapper](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/_modules/django/db/utils/#DatabaseErrorWrapper)

2nd EDIT:

you could catch the integrity error and access the `.messages` attribute from the database wrapper.

pseudo example:

```
try:
    # operation on database
except IntegrityError as ie:
    print(ie.wrapper.cursor.messages[:])
```

Comment: No, this is not inside a migration.

Answer (score 0):

I tend to use as less dependence as possible and leave 3rd party libs as they are.

Most of the time, i would log every sql insert/update/delete query. In this way, i can identify which query went wrong easily without extra effort. This allows me to track who did what at when in my system.

That happens to meet part of regulatory requirement on actions tracking in my industry.